# Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex graph with at most $100n$ triangles. Prove that $G$ has a triangle-free...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

> Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex graph with at most $100n$ triangles. Prove that $G$ has a triangle-free induced subgraph with at least $\frac{n}{15 \sqrt{3}}$ vertices.

My solution:

We pick each vertex independently with probability $p \in[0,1]$
(we choose it later). Let $X$ be a number of chosen vertices and $Y$
a number of chosen triangles. Then the number of good vertices is at least $X-Y$ (we throw out from each chosen triangle at least one (bad) vertex). Calculate the expectation of it.

$$E(X-Y) = E(X) -E(Y) \geq np-100n\cdot p^3$$
Now, the function $f(p) = p-100p^3$ has maximum at $p={\sqrt{3}\over 30}$  which give us $$E(X-Y) \geq {n\over 15\sqrt{3}}$$

So there must exists a subgraph with at least ${n\over 15\sqrt{3}}$ vertices with no triangle.

---

Now I have 2 questions:

- Is there a non probabilistic solution?
- Is there a better bound?

Comment: what is $Y$? bad vertices kept, or just bad vertices? if the latter, then it's not a random variable

Comment: First one @mathworker21

Comment: $E(Y) = 100np^3$? Do you want some inequality instead?

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks.

Comment: idk where $100np^3$ is coming from. the number of points in at least 1 triangle is at most $300n$, so wouldn't you get $300np$? can u explain the $100np^3$

Comment: Yes, $Y$ should be the number of chosen triangles. This is great @mathworker21 Thanks.

Comment: np. proof is correct now, but you should rewrite it to make it clear (no need to say "good vertices", and make it more clear that you're removing a vertex from each chosen triangle). i don't know the answer to the second or third question. for the third question, maybe you can try to show $\frac{n}{15\sqrt{3}}$ is tight by looking at a random graph on $n$ vertices (choose probability parameter so that with high probability, there are at most $100n$ triangles).

Comment: Bounds of the form cn are possible non-probabilistically; here's one with much worse constants: repeatedly delete vertices which are part of many, say >=200 triangles. At least n/2 vertices still remain, with each vertex being part of less than 200 triangles. Now among the remaining vertices, there's a 1/200 fraction which forms a triangle-free graph.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a better bound?

Here is an upper bound of $\frac{n}{13}$, i.e. a graph such that every $\frac{n}{13}+1$ vertices induce a subgraph containing a triangle.

Let $n$ be a multiple of $26$, and let $G$ be $\frac{n}{26}$ disjoint copies of $K_{26}$. The number of triangles is ${26 \choose 3}\frac{n}{26} = 100n$, and clearly the largest number of vertices such that the induced subgraph is triangle-free is $2\frac{n}{26} = \frac{n}{13}$.

Comment: +1!  haha, i love "numerology" like this.  who would have thought $100$ is related to $26$ this way?  ;)  BTW $15 \sqrt{3} \approx 25.98$ so the upper and lower bounds are only a factor of $2$ off.

Comment: @antkam please get them to match :)